# /etc/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so not found in docker image

Tags: apache, docker, apache-modules

When starting apache I get an error of `AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: No MPM loaded`

So I added the module:
`LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so`

/etc/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

```
apachectl -V | grep -i mp
```

returns:

```
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Server MPM:     prefork
Server compiled with....
```

How am I meant to load the module? Is the path different perhaps (I'm using the docker image of `php:5.6-apache-stretch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to include:

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
```

before loading the modules